# Distance between a point and a set 3

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Hi everyone: Let $A$ be a set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n>1$, and for $r>0$  let $B$ be the set of points having a distance equals to $r$ from $A$. Prove that for each boundary point $a$ of $A$, there exists a point $b\in B$ such that the distance between $a$ and $b$ equals $r$.

Comment: This is simply not true, unless $A$ is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

Let $A\subset\mathbb R^2$ be the set $\{(x,y\}:x \le 0\,\mathrm{or}\,y\le 0\}$, and take $r=1$. Then $B$ is equal to $\{(x,1):x \ge 1\}\cup\{(1,y):y\ge 1\}$.

[image]

$a=(0,0)$ is on the boundary of $A$, but there is no point $b\in B$ with $|a-b|=1$.